# frustrating Bug in Python global is not defined, but it is defined

Tags: python

```
import sys;
import os;
from DB import *;
import mysql.connector;

########################################################################
class htmlForm():
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        self.db = database(database.east_autoExpire);

    def maker(self,f):
        blabla

def main(f):
    htmlform = htmlForm();
    return htmlform.maker(f)
```

well when I run it, it works fine. However, when I call it by other procedure, it gave me global name "database" is not defined. However, it already is defined ahead!

from DB import *;

Comment: What do you mean by "the head"?

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Comment: `import *` → don't do that. Always name the imports you want to use. Precisely to avoid this kind of headache.

Comment: Not enough information to diagnose the error, particularly since stuff like `blabla` indicates this probably isn't a version of your code you actually ran. Most likely it's a circular import problem, but it could be any of a bunch of things.

Comment: Elaborating a bit on import: if you do `from DB import database`, you are absolutely sure that either `database` is found and is correctly imported, or it is not found and it raises an error immediately. When you do `import *`, there will never be an error, and you cannot know for sure what was imported. Maybe `database` was part of the heap of imported stuff, maybe not. Headache ensues.

Comment: @spectras you are correct. * seems like the reason. When I use import DB and try to use DB.database, it will work! However, when I try to use from DB import database,form; It told me "ImportError: cannot import name database",

Comment: @user2357112 it is enough information, The problem is that line. It doesn't matter

Comment: @RunpengChen that means the `database` symbol is created at a later point, after your file is imported but before your form is instanciated. Maybe because of circular references, or simply because it does not exist until some stuff is initialized, only way to know would be to check `DB` module's documentation or code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up the comments: a python module is simply a container, that has some stuff in it.

- `import DB` creates, in current module, a reference named `DB` to the `DB` module.
- `from DB import database` copies the reference from the `DB` module into the current module.
- `from DB import *` copies all it finds in `DB` module into current module (*). There is no difference with previous line, except you have no control on what you import, so there may be some stuff you think is imported but is not, or you can even overwrite some symbols. Suppose, for instance, that `DB` module contains:

  ```
  sys = 'foo'
  ```

  Then your `from DB import *` will overwrite your `import sys` with `'foo'`

Notice, however, a very important difference between `import DB` and the other two possibilites: the first line makes the module available. This means that when you do `DB.database`, this will look for `database` in the `DB` module at the moment the line is executed.

Usually, as modules are pretty static, it does not matter. In your case, however, it seems the `DB` module does not have the `database` reference when you first import it. It creates it at a later point. Therefore, `from DB import *` will not copy it, and `from DB import database` fails loudly.

You then have two options:

- just import the module, and not look for `database` in it until you actually want it (`import DB` and then later `DB.database`)
- or defer the import until you need it (what you had done first, putting `from DB import database` inside the `__init__` method).

**TLDR**: don't use `import *`, and all other issues will become obvious.

<sub>(*) if `DB.__all__` is defined, only those names will be copied.</sub>